# Char seems to be an int no matter what I do, not sure what is happening

Tags: c, struct, char, int

Here is my code, I'm trying to make bit fields with a struct and order them lsB first:

```
struct rhmp{
    unsigned int type1:4;
    unsigned int dstPort:14;
    unsigned int srcPort:14;
};

struct rhmp rhmp1;

rhmp1.type1 = 3;
rhmp1.dstPort = 122;
rhmp1.srcPort = 300;

char firstByte = (((char)rhmp1.type1 & 0xF) << 4) + (((char)rhmp1.dstPort & 0x3C00)>>10);
char secondByte = (rhmp1.dstPort & 0x3FC) >> 2;
char thirdByte = ((rhmp1.dstPort & 0x3) << 6) + ((rhmp1.srcPort & 0x3F00)>>8);
//char thirdByte = 0x81;
char fourthByte = (rhmp1.srcPort & 0xFF);

char messageToSend[4] = {firstByte, secondByte, thirdByte, fourthByte};

printf("RHMP byte 1: %X\n",firstByte);
printf("RHMP byte 2: %X\n",(int)secondByte);
printf("RHMP byte 3: %X\n",(int)thirdByte);
printf("RHMP byte 3 should be: %X\n",(int) ((rhmp1.dstPort & 0x3) << 6) + ((rhmp1.srcPort & 0x3F00)>>8));
printf("RHMP byte 4: %X\n",(int)fourthByte);`
```

This is printing out the following:

```
RHMP byte 1: 30
RHMP byte 2: 1E
RHMP byte 3: FFFFFF81
RHMP byte 3 should be: 81
RHMP byte 4: 2C
```

No matter what I do, byte 3 seems to be a 32 bit value. Even when I assign it to 0x81 it doesn't work. What is happening here?

Comment: `0x81` is a negative number when stored in a `char`. Try declaring byte 3 as an `unsigned char`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Still not sure why is became 32 bits but the FFFFF's make sense now.

Comment: All `char` variables are `signed char` by default. Typecast it to `unsigned char` instead `int`. 0x81 is considered as negative number hence leading one's are printed.

Comment: Re "*All `char` variables are `signed char` by default.*", That's actually up to the individual compiler.

Comment: @user3386109: Whether `char` is signed or unsigned depends on the C implementation.

Comment: The code causes undefined behaviour by using `%X` to print an `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unqualified `char` is a signed type on your system —it varies by implementation— and an unqualified `int` always refers to a `signed int`.

`thirdByte` has a value of -127. When you cast it to `signed int`, it produces a `signed int` with the same value (-127).

You can solve your problem by using `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

Comment: Technical note: Even if `char` is signed in an implementation, it is still a different type from `signed char`; `char` never refers to `signed char`. (In contrast, `int` is the same type as `signed int`.)

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Thanks. Adjusted